# What is the splitting field of $X^{20}-1$ over $\Bbb F_3$. And how to factor $X^{20}-1$ in $\Bbb F_3[X]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm doing some exercises to prepare for my exam:

> What is the splitting field of $X^{20}-1$ over $\Bbb F_3$. And how to
>   factor $X^{20}-1$ in $\Bbb F_3[X]$.

I've no idea how to tackle this exercise.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would start with $X^{20} - 1 = (X^{10} - 1)(X^{10} + 1)$...

Comment: There are two theorems that can help you with this. Are you familiar with them? 1) $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\Bbb F_p$, 2) $x^{p^n} - x$ is precisely the product of all irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_p[x]$ of degree $d$ where $d$ runs through the divisors of $n$.

Comment: Hint: don't look for an appropriate polynomial $f$ such that your field is ${\mathbb F}_3[X]/(f)$; instead, look at fields ${\mathbb F}_{3^k}[X]$ and see what roots of unity they contain.

Comment: The multiplicative group of the quartic extension $\Bbb{F}_{81}$ is cyclic of order 80. No smaller field will do. Thus you get a bunch of quartic factors and a few lower degree ones.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for a general method of computing splitting fields. However, there is something special about the case you mentioned: splitting fields of polynomials of the form $x^n-1$ are called cyclotomic fields. There is a theorem for cyclotomic fields over finite fields, stating that:

The $n$-th cyclotomic field $K^{n}$ over $\Bbb F_p$ with $p,n$ coprime has degree $$[K^{n}:\Bbb F_p] = ord_n(p)$$ where $ord_n(p)$ is the lowest $k$ such that $n \mid p^k-1$.

See Thm 8.12 in http://www-groups.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~neunhoef/Teaching/ff/ffchap4.pdf